# How to find all consecutive letters with count from string provided by user?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a code in Java which will find all the consecutive letters in string provided by user and also provide its count.

For example:
User has provided string: "aaastt rr".

I am expecting the result as below:

a - 3

t - 2

r - 2

I have written below code as per my understanding but not getting the result as expected.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConsecutiveCharacters {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter string: ");
    char s[] = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
    int count = 1;
    for(int i =0;i<s.length-1;i++){
        if(s[i]==s[i+1]){
            count++;
            System.out.println(s[i] + "-" + count);

        }
    }

}
}
```

I am getting result:

a-2

a-3

t-4

r-5

which is not I am expecting.

Please have a look, and let me know where I am missing.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I entered "aaba adc", should the output be:
a - 2
b - 1
a - 2
d - 1
c - 1

?

Comment: you need to reset the counter when you reach a new character, basically do an else{ count = 0;} after your if

Comment: There are some solutions here
https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/group-count-repeating-characters-in-string/

Comment: @JoshEvans: No I am looking for only consecutive letters,and if there is a space between two same characters then it should not treated as consecutive letter. Example: for "aaaba addc", result should be: a-3 d-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are never resetting your counter when you run into a new character within the array.

Use the starting character and increment as you go and change the character whenever a new one is found and only print the previous char and count if the count is greater than 1. Note the edge case where the last of the characters are consecutive.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter string: ");
char s[] = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
HashMap<Character, Integer> charsFound = new HashMap<>();
int count = 1;
char c = s[0];
for(int i = 1;i < s.length; i++)
{
    //check the edge case where the last of the array is consecutive chars
    if(c==s[i] && count >= 1 && s.length - 1 == i)
    {
        if(!charsFound.containsKey(c))
            charsFound.put(c, ++count);
        else if(charsFound.get(c) < ++count)
            charsFound.put(c, count);
    }
    //increment the count if the character is the same one
    else if(c==s[i])
    {
        count++;
    }
    //consecutive chain is broken, reset the count and our current character
    else
    {
        if(count > 1)
        {
            if(!charsFound.containsKey(c))
                charsFound.put(c, count);
            else if(charsFound.get(c) < count)
                charsFound.put(c, count);
        }
        //reset your variables for a new character
        c = s[i];
        count = 1;
    }
}

for (char knownCharacters : charsFound.keySet())
    if (charsFound.get(knownCharacters) > 1)
        System.out.println(knownCharacters + "-" + charsFound.get(knownCharacters));
```

Output

```
Enter string:
aabbbt s.r r rr
a-2
b-3
r-2

Enter string: 
aaastt rr
a-3
t-2
r-2

Enter string: 
aayy t t t.t ty ll fffff
a-2
y-2
l-2
f-5

Enter string: 
aa b aa c aaaaa
a-5
```

Comment: Considering the OP wanted each character printed once, is this actually an acceptable answer? I agree about the `HashMap` however.

Comment: Thanks Raz, it helps.

@17slim: Yes, I was looking for the code where we will be able to find all consecutive characters even if they are repeating. Yes, HashMap method is also working but it not finding all consecutive. Also I have not much knowledge on HashMap method, so can't say more. Is there any other way using HasMap where we can find all consecutive even they are repeating.

Thanks both for your help.

Comment: added the hasmap functionality to the code. just wanted to give a solution to fix the current code not resetting the counter. I was hoping the poster could use the code to expand on the idea and use a hashmap. But here you go @Shan